# How to play spotify full tracks in browser

Tags: javascript, spotify

I want to use the spotify api to build a simple audio player embedded into a chrome extension. I've integrated the auth flow and I'm able to get a token to use for the api requests. I'm looking at the documentation to find a way to play the user playlists or searched tracks but I'm not able to find any useful information. They have only [this SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/) but a premium account is needed.

Is possible to use the spotify uri to play a full track or playlist after authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's currently no way to play the full song using the Web API. If you want full tracks to be playable from a website, you can use the Spotify Play Button. If you want to build a mobile application, you can do playback of full tracks using the Android and/or iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it right now using the Spotify Web API and this:

https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js

I'm running this locally to provide refresh tokens:

https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples

I'm still figuring it out, but I definitely have things playing in my browser on local.

Comment: Can you show a sample of code please?Your answer isn't clear about how you achived this. I only see the official spotify JS client library linked and the sample code for the auth flow, nothing useful or no informtion about how you have achived the scope